# $(x^n)^2=x^n$ for all $n\geq 1$. $x$ is idemotent ring where $x^2= x$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am asked to prove the above 
I have been trying a lot but my teacher did not like they way I solved it,he did not even tell me what is wrong with it.i was thinking if $n=3$ then $x^{2n}$ will be equal to $x^6$ is equal to $$x\cdot x\cdot x\cdot x\cdot x\cdot x=x^6=x^2\cdot x^2\cdot x^2$$
But we know that $x=x^2$
So $x^{2n}=x\cdot x\cdot x = x^3=x^n$
"............sorry can't answer my question now but is this what u mean

(x^n)^2 = x^n for all n>= 1
now for n = 1, we have 
x^2 = x which is true for x a member of r
for n+1 we need to show
(x^n+1)^2 = x^n+1
(x^n+1)^2 = (x^n * x)(x^n * x)
(x^n+1)^2 = (x^n)^2 * x^2
(x^n+1)^2 = x^n * x
(x^n+1)^2 = x^n+1

Comment: You should use induction.

Comment: This is what u mean
(x^n)^2 = x^n for all n>= 1
now for n = 1, we have 
x^2 = x which is true for x a member of r
for n+1 we need to show
(x^n+1)^2 = x^n+1
(x^n+1)^2 = (x^n * x)(x^n * x)
(x^n+1)^2 = (x^n)^2 * x^2
(x^n+1)^2 = x^n * x
(x^n+1)^2 = x^n+1

Comment: $x$ is an idempotent ring? or $x$ is an element of a ring $R$ that is idempotent?

Comment: X is an element in R

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(x^n)^2=x^{2n}=(x^2)^n$.

Comment: Thanks I did that one but he did not like it too.

Comment: Well, if he didn't like it, why didn't he like it?

Comment: He did not say why but I think he wants me to solve in this way 
(x^n)^2 = x^n for all n>= 1
now for n = 1, we have 
x^2 = x which is true for x a member of r
for n+1 we need to show
(x^n+1)^2 = x^n+1
(x^n+1)^2 = (x^n * x)(x^n * x)
(x^n+1)^2 = (x^n)^2 * x^2
(x^n+1)^2 = x^n * x
(x^n+1)^2 = x^n+1

Comment: Easier this way. He might want you to prove $(x^n)^m = x^{nm}$ for positive integers $n,m$, which you can easily do by induction on $m$. Then the answer just falls out.

Comment: Can u pls explain.

Comment: What didn't you understand?